# WSO2EI API list

Tags: wso2, api-manager

I need to get all apis(list of apis) with their parameters from wso2ei. I could do that with wso2 api-manager with curl command.how can I do this with curl command in wso2ei?

Answer (score 0):

There aren't any rest APIs available in wso2ei to get the list of APIs.

Comment: I can access to list of API with SOAP admin services. but i want to get the list of parameters and their types. in wso2ei or wso2am with admin services. can any one help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve API list and details from RestApiAdmin admin service (SOAP service). You can get parameters and types from the WSDL. Follow [1] to retrieve WSDL of RestApiAdmin Admin service.

Sample curl to retrieve API list:

```
curl -k -v -X POST \
  https://localhost:9443/services/RestApiAdmin \
  -H 'Accept: */*' \
  -H 'Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=' \
  -H 'SOAPAction: "urn:getAPIsForListing"' \
  -d '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://org.apache.axis2/xsd">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <xsd:getAPIsForListing>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <xsd:pageNumber>0</xsd:pageNumber>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <xsd:itemsPerPage>10</xsd:itemsPerPage>
        </xsd:getAPIsForListing>
    </soapenv:Body>
```

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI610/Calling+Admin+Services+from+Apps#CallingAdminServicesfromApps-Discoveringtheadminservices